# Can Nodejs retrieve data from Meteor mini mongo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to use Nodejs to get data from Meteorjs mini mongo database. Here is my code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor', function(err, db) {
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected to Database");
  var test = db.collection("apps");
  test.insert({"_id":"selfDefinedID"}, function(err,docs){
    console.log("docs inserted");
    console.log(docs);
  });
  test.find({"_id":"selfDefinedID"}).toArray(function(err,docs){
    console.log("docs founded");
    console.log(docs);
  });
});
```

Insert data works fine. But, I can't retrieve data from meteor mini mongo database. And I got an error:

```
{ [MongoError: Connection Closed By Application] name: 'MongoError' }
```

Is it possible to retrieve Meteor mini mongo data using Nodejs? If possible, how?

Comment: When you talk about "mini mongo", are you referring to the database on the client?  Mongo on the server is just Mongo.

Comment: @Mike I'm using Meteor version MongoDB. It's not regular MongoDB. I'm just curious is this an issue for meteor mongo. It should work with regular MongoDB.

Comment: @Mike Since it's not regular MongoDB, I'm just curious if this is an issue for meteor mongo or maybe there is a meteor way to find data with node.

Comment: Minimongo is the javascript implementation that sits client side, but I'm thinking that's not what you want.  If you run it once and it fails, you say the data is there.  What happens on the second run if you comment out the insert and just run the find? (I'd test this myself but not in the position to run it at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

The database meteor uses is a normal mongo database. You can connect to it like any other mongo db. If you are still in development mode, then the database runs at `mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor`, otherwise, in a bundled app, it's just the db you specified yourself using `MONGO_URL`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I did use mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor for the connection. It works for update and insert, but find.

Answer (score 0):

On a windows machine, I created a new, blank, meteor project, and started it up.  I then created a test script, npm installed the mongodb library, and ran your script and it worked fine.  First run I get "docs inserted" and "docs founded", on subsequent runs obviously the insert is failing, but the find still works.

So two questions, first is this the same script your getting the error with?  And two, if you create a blank meteor project and try it do you get the same error?